# Ruby gems path issue (system vs brew)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew

I'm having an issue with homebrew looking to the system gems when the system gems aren't in the $PATH.

Here is my `gem env` to show that my gems are installed in my .rvm/gems directory:

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/scott/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
     - /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
     - :benchmark => false
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
     - http://gems.github.com
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     - /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin
     - /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /Users/scott/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/scott/.composer/vendor/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
```

Now here is the error message I keep getting on various commands (this in particular was from `brew services start httpd22`):

```
Error: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/compile.log' to see what happened.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:265:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:69:in `compile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:109:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `call'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.1/gem_make.out
```

See how it's looking to the system version of Ruby & Gems? I have XCode installed and up to date.

`brew doctor` yields no results and `brew update` is ready to brew.

I'm using OS 10.10.3. Anything I've left out, just ask.

**EDIT**

Here is my .zshrc $PATH export:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

**EDIT 2**

`$GEM_HOME`

```
/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
```

`$GEM_PATH`

```
/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2:/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The only significant difference I see in your  `gem env` output and mine is:   `-RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby`.  The ruby version is the version I have set as the default in rvm. Then, the last thing in my shell configuration file( .bash_profile) is: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` and 

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: You can also try the zsh tests proposed by rvm here: https://rvm.io/integration/zsh

Comment: Updated my `RUBY EXECUTABLE` to point to the rvm path. Didn't help, but good catch nonetheless.

Comment: *Updated my RUBY EXECUTABLE to point to the rvm path. Didn't help* Yeah, I don't have that environment variable set, so I don't think rvm reads it.  What about the zsh tests?  By the way, I stopped using homebrew because of all the path issues.  I install everything from source.  homebrew was a bust for me.

Comment: Same issue for the zsh tests, no change. I'm not a ruby developer, so having issues with Ruby while trying to run a non-system apache are quite frustrating. I might have to ditch it as well.

Comment: I've never used the system stuff for anything.  I install my own Apache and Ruby versions--although I still haven't gotten around to re-installing Apache for my new OSX 10.10.2.  And now I remember...rvm uses homebrew for setup.  I just don't have a separate homebrew install to use as a package manager for my Mac.

Comment: Can you post the steps you took to install rvm?  Do you know why your RUBY_EXECUTABLE is pointing to `/usr/local`?

Comment: Are you using oh-my-zsh?  If so, there is a trouble shooting tip at the bottom of this page: https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting

Comment: What other commands do you see this with? How is Nokogiri involved? A `brew` invocation should not be doing that on its own.

Comment: I don't even know what Nokogiri is, it's just in the error message I got when trying to run certain brew commands. I ended up just wiping homebrew and user installed ruby and starting over. If it pops up again I'll let you know.

Comment: Reinstalled homebrew and uninstalled rvm. Added rbenv just to see if that changed anything. Still getting errors from the system gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, the system rubygems.rb was referencing the wrong version of Ruby. More details here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/31220

Answer (score 0):

looking at brew:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/bin/brew

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/bin/brew#L22

so brew is upsetting the GEM_PATH and doing its own thing.

Comment: Added my GEM_PATH to the original post.

If that's the culprit it looks like the only fix is to edit the Homebrew files, which I'd rather not do.